# Why can I import animation components from both @angular/animations and @angular/core?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I recently updated to angular 4 and checking the [animations docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations) I see I should import trigger, animate and transition from @angular/animations.

```
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';
```

In my project however I have been importing from @angular/core so far and everything works fine, even after animations were separated from core.

```
import { ... trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/core';
```

Why does angular core still hold these animation components ? Backwards compatability maybe ? Why not just remove it completely from core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports from @angular/core were **deprecated**.

https://angular.io/api/core/animate

This symbol has moved. Please Import from @angular/animations instead!

I think they will remove them from **core** one day.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#installing-rc1). It is deprecated but you can still use it in your app. Not all programmers have the luxury to update their apps on every new release. It is just a warning that you should update your code, so that when the major release happens, your migration will be smooth. Hope this helps.